# What kind of bug in flash video playback can show this image?

Tags: actionscript-3, video-streaming, flash

This picture is shown when one of my friends tries to play the video in my flash program. I use standard Flash Video things to play it (a media.Video class). I don't have a slighets idea what could cause such a peculiar bug???
Here is the image:
[image]

Comment: a broken graphics card.